# How do I know when to use protocols and delegates, and what are they? ( swift 4.2 )

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, protocols

I was wondering how protocols and delegates are used in swift. I’m sort of an experienced programmer ( about 6 months of experience ) but I’m still confused. Thanks!

---

New question:

How are delegates and protocols used in swift?

Comment: A protocol is a "promise" or "contract" which states that any reference which conforms to the protocol is guaranteed to implement (the non-optional) functionality. A delegate is a concept where work or functionality is "delegated" to some other object.  In many cases protocols are used to describe the work that delegates are expected to perform.  Things like `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` are (kind of) examples of the concept

Comment: https://useyourloaf.com/blog/quick-guide-to-swift-delegates/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Protocol:

Think of a protocol as a lingo. It's a specialized vocabulary that objects use to talk to each other. A protocol defines a set of methods and properties that any object that "conforms" to that protocol is guaranteed to have.

Imagine a short-order cook. The short order cook knows the lingo of the restaurant. "I need a #7, well, with everything but onions."

The wait staff doesn't need to know who is working that night. They just place their orders, and the cook cooks them. In fact, the cook doesn't even need to be human. If you could build a robot who understood and could follow the short-order-cook protocol, and could cook the food, you could replace the human with the robot, and the wait-staff wouldn't need to change how they worked at all.

A protocol is very much like that.

Delegates use protocols, but that's not the only way they are used.

---

### Delegate:

A delegate is an object that does a specific job, and that is guaranteed to understand a specific protocol. In the example above, the short-order-cook is the delegate of the restaurant. You don't know **what** a delegate object is - you just know that it knows how to cook food. You could replace the short order cook with a different short-order cook, and everything works exactly the same as long as they both conform to the short-order-cook protocol. (A delegate is usually defined as an object that conforms to a protocol rather than being a specific class.)

A delegate can also be an object that is used to customize the behavior of another object. For `UITableViews`, for example, the delegate does things like specify the row height for cells, determines which cells can be selected, handles selection actions, provides header/footer views, and stuff like that.

You frequently provide a delegate to customize the behavior of complex Apple UI objects like table views.